# Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

In the inline math mode (`$...$`), if the formula is too long, LaTeX will try to break it on operators, e.g.

```
very long text followed by a very long equation like $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l$ etc
```

may be rendered as

```
very long text followed
by a very long equation
like a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+
j+k+l etc
```

However, the break won't happen if they are separated by commas, e.g.

```
very long text followed by a very long equation like $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l$ etc
```

will overflow the page like

```
very long text followed
by a very long equation
like a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l
etc
```

How to make LaTeX able to insert line breaks after a comma too?

Comment: I tried breqn but it uses "expl3.sty" which can not be found by Latex ALTHOUGH I downloaded it and put in the same folder where breqn.sty exists!

Comment: @Ahmad: If you've got a question, then you should ask it in a new post. Please do this with the "Ask Question" link. In your new question you could link to this one.

Comment: @Ahmad: Just a note to confirm Hendrik's comment, this ought to be reposted as a question for you to get the best chance of it being answered.

Comment: Late to the party, but just for the record: You can make the comma be treated like a binary or relation operator with the commands `\mathbin{,}` or `\mathrel{,}`. For instance, `$stuff \mathrel{,} morestuff$` will allow the linebreak between the two stuffs.

Comment: Automatical breaking at + does happen neither between \left and \right nor between { and }. I had to suppress them manually in latex's export of matlab's Live Editor.

Comment: Ah and please see more recent question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555544/how-to-automatically-linebreak-an-inline-math-formula

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If the expression contains many commas then consider to break it into several math expressions, separated by commas. It reads like a list of math expressions. This way TeX can break the line.

To achieve line breaks after a comma, you could insert `\allowbreak` after the comma and before the next math symbol. If necessary, leave a blank after `\allowbreak`.

If you would like to have a document wide solution, you could redefine the comma. One solution, following the tip [here](http://users.ugent.be/~gdschrij/LaTeX/textricks.html#mathcommabreak) would be:

```
\makeatletter
\def\old@comma{,}
\catcode`\,=13
\def,{%
  \ifmmode%
    \old@comma\discretionary{}{}{}%
  \else%
    \old@comma%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. My expression is actually a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) with 48 elements, so splitting them into several expressions may not sound mathematically logical. I will try `\allowbreak`.

Comment: +1, excellent answer! However, there's a complication: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19094/1347.

Comment: Note that the `\allowbreak` solution does not work if you have `\left...\right` delimiters that span the break in your equation

Comment: Any trick for `\allowbreak` working in `\left...\right` delimiters?

Comment: This document-wide solution seems to break tikz...

Comment: @xuhdev if you use `~` in math environment for spacing, then redefining `~` instead of `,` (with old value `\ `) is a solution which does not break tikz.

Comment: Thank you for your code. Your code works for me.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus : one possibility (not ideal but can work in some circumstances) is to replace `\left(, \right)` e.g. by `\Big(, \Big)`. Then allowbreak or linebreak will work.

Answer (score 44):

You could take a look at the [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package, which is aimed at solving this problem in a general sense.

Comment: Wow, `breqn` allows \left and \right to work across line breaks!

Comment: Indeed, amongst other things. The late Michael Downes was a _very_ clever guy!

Comment: For commas, this does not work with all types of atoms. [See the discussion here.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60746/breqn-does-not-automatically-break-lines)

Answer (score 21):

Here is a solution that doesn't make the comma globally active:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\splitatcommas}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup
    \edef~{\mathchar\the\mathcode`, \penalty0 \noexpand\hspace{0pt plus 1em}}%
  }\mathcode`,="8000 #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{2pt}\setlength{\lineskip}{3pt} % for this particular case

$\splitatcommas{
  \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{5},\frac{8}{13},\frac{21}{34},\frac{55}{89},
  \frac{144}{233},\frac{377}{610},\frac{987}{1597},\frac{2584}{4181},
  \frac{6765}{10946},\frac{17711}{28657},\frac{46368}{75025},
  \frac{121393}{196418},\frac{317811}{514229},\frac{832040}{1346269},
  \frac{2178309}{3524578},\frac{5702887}{9227465},
  \frac{14930352}{24157817},\frac{39088169}{63245986},\frac{102334155}{165580141}
}$

\end{document}
```

The setting of `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip` are for the particular case where fractions are needed in the argument.

[image]

A variant that allows nesting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\splitatcommas}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifnum\mathcode`,="8000
  \else
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup
      \edef~{\mathchar\the\mathcode`, \penalty0 \noexpand\hspace{0pt plus 1em}}%
    }\mathcode`,="8000
  \fi
  #1%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\tuple}[1]{(\splitatcommas{#1})}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{\splitatcommas{#1}\}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{2pt}\setlength{\lineskip}{3pt} % for this particular case

$\splitatcommas{
  \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{5},\frac{8}{13},\frac{21}{34},\frac{55}{89},
  \frac{144}{233},\frac{377}{610},\frac{987}{1597},\frac{2584}{4181},
  \frac{6765}{10946},\frac{17711}{28657},\frac{46368}{75025},
  \frac{121393}{196418},\frac{317811}{514229},\frac{832040}{1346269},
  \frac{2178309}{3524578},\frac{5702887}{9227465},
  \frac{14930352}{24157817},\frac{39088169}{63245986},\frac{102334155}{165580141}
}$

$\set{
  \tuple{a,b,c,d},\tuple{1,2,3,4,5,6},\tuple{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88},
  \tuple{a,b,c,d},\tuple{1,2,3,4,5,6},\tuple{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88},
  \tuple{a,b,c,d},\tuple{1,2,3,4,5,6},\tuple{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88},
  \tuple{a,b,c,d},\tuple{1,2,3,4,5,6},\tuple{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88}
}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Nasser With `breqn` this is guaranteed not to work. Probably something can be done, I'll work on your problem later.

Comment: Did you manage to find the workaround for `breqn`?

Comment: @azetina I don't consider `breqn` a usable piece of software.

Comment: @egreg Nice solution! But if I do nesting like `\splitatcommas{a , b,\splitatcommas{c, d}` I’m getting errors like _! Bad mathchar (32768)._ Do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: @Ronny I'm not sure I understand what the nesting is for.

Comment: @egreg The nesting occurs if I use `\splitatcommas` in some math commands I defined myself. E. g. `\newcommand{\tuple}[1]{(\splitatcommas{#1})}` and `\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{\splitatcommas{#1}\}}`. If I use them like `\set{\tuple{a,b}}`, I get the error above.

Comment: @Ronny Added the variant

Comment: @egreg You are great! Thank you very much. I’ve looked for something like `\ifnum\mathcode`,="8000`, but wasn’t able to implement. My dissertation will look much better.

Comment: @egreg I tried your code with a set of ordered pairs but it breaks lines also within the pairs. How can one modify so that with {(a,b), (c,d)} it can split at '), ' but not at 'a,b' and 'c,d'?

Comment: @Geoff Did you see `\tuple`?

Comment: @egreg According to the image it breaks the tuple (1,2,3,4,5,6) whereas I don't want tuples to be broken.

Comment: @Geoff Ah, OK. You need to define differently `\tuple`, then. Something like ``\mathchardef\standardcomma=\mathcode`\, \newcommand{\tuple}[1]{\begingroup\mathcode`\,=\standardcomma(#1)\endgroup}``

Comment: It's as "simple" as that! Many thanks!

Comment: I know the question asks about inline math, but I was hoping that this would work inside `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`. It does not.

Comment: @Gus TeX does not break lines inside `equation`

Answer (score 16):

Just try inserting `\allowbreak` in between your inline equations.

$x_1, x_2,...\allowbreak, y_1,y_2,y_n$.
The line won't reach out and break at before y_1

Comment: Welcome ! Could you please expand your answer a bit, with a small example for instance ?

Comment: That's it! It also works in plain TeX.

Answer (score 4):

In luatex you have a new possibility that does not involve active characters, you can declare `,` to be a `mathbin` (like `+`) so that line breaking is allowed and then set the mathord-mathbin spacing to zero so it gets no space before, like punctuation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$
\mathcode`\,="213B % mathbin
\Umathordbinspacing\textstyle 0mu % no space before
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can split the equation into several sub equation using $, and if you are using braces use \left. and \right. (with dot) to balance the braces.

Example:

```
 $X = \left\{\right.a$, $b$, $c$, $d\left.\right\}$
```

X = { a, b, c, d }

This should allow line breaks behind the commas.

Comment: You might as well just omit `\left` and `\right`. Putting the matching brace directly adjacent obviates any point to having scaling braces at all.

Comment: disregarding the pointless `\left` and `\right` commands, ;) it is a quick workaround.