# "Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode" breaks citations

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, citing

In answering another question [allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/1347), [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/1960#1960) suggested two excellent ways to allow line breaks in inline math mode after `,`. One way was to use the `\allowbreak` command after the comma, and the other way was to globally redefine `,` so that line breaks are allowed.

I used the second approach, and was really fond of it, until I noted that the command `\cite{}` no longer works as expected: If I cited more than one reference, it showed `[?]` instead of the correct citation. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%----------Redefining `,` ------------------%
\makeatletter
\def\old@comma{,}
\catcode`\,=13
\def,{%
  \ifmmode%
    \old@comma\discretionary{}{}{}%
  \else%
    \old@comma%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\cite{A,B}

\begin{thebibliography}{A}
\bibitem{A} ABC
\bibitem{B} DEF
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

What is wrong with redefining `,`? How to correct it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When `\cite` tries to split the argument, it doesn't find the expected delimiter, which is a category 12 comma and is different from a category 13 comma.

The correct way, other than using **breqn** is to make the comma "math active", just as it is done in the package **icomma**.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\mathcomma\mathcode`\,
  \mathcode`\,="8000 
}
{\catcode`,=\active
  \gdef,{\mathcomma\discretionary{}{}{}}
}
```

But I should warn about making this definition, as TeX might break also formulas such as $(a,b)$. I would suggest

```
\mathchardef\breakingcomma\mathcode`\,
{\catcode`,=\active
  \gdef,{\breakingcomma\discretionary{}{}{}}
}
\newcommand{\mathlist}[1]{$\mathcode`\,=\string"8000 #1$}
```

and using `\mathlist{a,b,c,d}` for a list that can be split across lines. (The `\string` is useful in connection with **babel**, for some languages make the double quote active.)

Comment: Is it possible to change the catcode of `,` only in the mathmode, so that `\cite` does not encounter such problem?

Comment: @Sadeq: the first piece of code I proposed does just this.

Comment: +1, cool that `\mathlist`!

Comment: Do I execute your top block of code (what's above "But I should warn") at the beginning of the preamble, after I 've loaded all needed packages, or just at the end of the preamble (after having defined all of my macros)? Or it doesn't matter? (And, is it different from the `\AtBeginDocument`-block and the `\catcode`-group thereafter?)

Comment: @LoverofStructure It shouldn't matter where you put the definitions. The second method shouldn't have any problem with other packages; in case some package or macro wants to make the comma an active character there would, of course, be a conflict.

Comment: (1) I think a very useful thing would be a way to set the comma to be math-active by default but to allow manual overrides (one could call it `\disallowlinebreak`). (2) Similarly, if I include `\allowbreak` in a macro, I'd like a manual way of disabling this (for both the case where `\allowbreak` occurs at the beginning and where it occurs at the end of a macro definition). — Let me know if you think it'd be useful for me to ask about these two things in one or two separate questions.