# Environment to allow line breaks at "," in math mode

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, environments

I find the question and accepted answer to [Allowing line break at `,` in inline math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode) very useful, BUT I would like to make an environment (e.g. "allowbreaks") out of it. The problem is that I'm not able to. Let me explain the idea:

```
\begin{allowbreaks}
Commas are modified in such a way that they allow breaks in
inline mathmode $(a,b,c)$ only within this environment.
\end{allowbreaks}
```

Is it possible somehow, please?

**edit:** I renamed the environment to `allowbreaks`, because of naming conflicts with the command `allowbreak`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can locally modify the behavior of the comma, allowing a break. The trick is to make it "math active":

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{allowbreaks}
  {\mathactivatecomma
   \mathcode`\,=\string"8000
   \ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\mathactivatecomma}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\,
  \lowercase{\endgroup\edef~}{\mathchar\the\mathcode`\,\penalty0 }}

\begin{document}
\parbox{1cm}{abc def
\begin{allowbreaks}
$a,b,c,d,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$
\end{allowbreaks}
haaa 
$a,b,c,d,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$}
\end{document}
```

You'll see that the first math formula is broken, while the second one isn't.

However, the method proposed in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19100/4427) is, in my opinion, better: use `\mathlist{a,b,c,d}` for a list of math variables that can be broken at commas.

Comment: Thanks, but @Herbert's method seems to perform slightly better at formatting. The `\mathlist` option is surely very interesting and I'll probably end up using it some other time, but at the moment possibly breaking at every comma is exactly what I want to achieve, since the variables I'm listing are quite long tuples.

Comment: Herbert's solution *seems* slightly better at formatting. Actually it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{allowbreaks}
  {\mathcode`\,="213B}
  {}

\begin{document}
\rightskip=11cm
foo $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$
foo bar baz

\begin{allowbreaks}
foo $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$
foo bar baz
\end{allowbreaks}

foo $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This adds spaces on *both* sides of the comma; they don't appear here because the formulas are shrinked at their maximum.

Comment: Woops... thanks for pointing it out @egreg, I didn't noticed it before!