# Inline math overflow does not happen with minipages, but everywhere else

Tags: math-mode, margins, minipage

When writing in a minipage environment, unsplittable math formulas **never** spill into the right margin. Instead, spacing is introduced in the current line and the formula is moved to the next line.

However, doing the same in free flowing "top level" text results in a visually most unappealing overflow, see example below.

I had a look at the manual penalties, but nothing seems to fit. How do I reproduce the minipage overflow behaviour everywhere else?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
This is an example paragraph inside a \textit{minipage} showing how text 
    should flow, notice how nothing is pushed onto the margins:

\textbf{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
 tempor incididunt ut  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
 quodque $P, Q , R , S ,T \ldots, X, Y, Z$, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
\end{minipage}  
\vspace{2em}

This is an example paragraph without any sections inside the main document,
  and here the math environment overflows into the margin:

\textbf{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
 tempor incididunt ut  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
 quodque $P, Q , R , S ,T \ldots, X, Y, Z$, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.  
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: `\sloppy` will fix this case.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Usage of `\sloppy` is the last option (like usage of `minipage`, by the way). You can allow breaks at any place of the math (except inside groups) by `\allowbreak` command. The spaces in the first example are so huge!

Comment: @tohecz  Maybe "fix" wasn't the right word to use.  What I meant was that `\sloppy` would cause the top-level text to mimic the minipage.  But you are right, the minipage is not appealing to look at.  In fact, it is quite... sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should compare like with like.  If you use `\showthe\linewidth` on the main part of you document you will see that its value is `345.0pt` which is slightly more than `12cm = 341.43306pt`.  The easiest way to make a genuine test is to write

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
 ...
\end{minipage}
```

Anyway, given that, you still get a similar difference in output.  This is mostly caused by the fact that `minipage` calls `\sloppy` when it starts.

Going the opposite way to what you ask, you can undo that particular setting globally by

```
\makeatletter
\def\@minipagerestore{\fussy}
\makeatother
```

With these two changes

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}    

\makeatletter
\def\@minipagerestore{\fussy}
\makeatother
\begin{document}    

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
This is an example paragraph inside a \textit{minipage} showing how text 
    should flow, notice how nothing is pushed onto the margins:

\textbf{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
 tempor incididunt ut  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
 quodque $P, Q , R , S ,T \ldots, X, Y, Z$, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
\end{minipage}  
\vspace{2em}

This is an example paragraph without any sections inside the main document,
  and here the math environment overflows into the margin:

\textbf{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
 tempor incididunt ut  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
 quodque $P, Q , R , S ,T \ldots, X, Y, Z$, quis nostrud exercitation
 ullamco.  

\end{document}
```

you get

[image: Sample output]

Notice that there is no space between the paragraphs in the `minipage`.  This is because `minipage` sets `\parskip` to `0pt`, but in `letter` class it is otherwise set to `6.99997pt`.

A list of parameters that `minipage` sets as standard can be found in the [`source2e` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e).  There you can read that it also sets to `0pt` the following parameters

```
\parindent
\@totalleftmargin
\leftskip
\rightskip
\@rightskip
```

Additionally, it sets

```
\parfillskip = 0pt plus 1fil
\lineskip = \normallineskip
\baselineskip = \normalbaselineskip

\@listdepth = \@mplistdepth
```

the latter is initially `0`, and  `@minipage` is set to true: quite a number of commands check this last value during their operation and so behave differently in a `minipage`.

Anyway, the simplest way to get `minipage`s linebreaking is to issue `\sloppy`, as Steven Segletes says.  Of coures, now you are throwing away many of LaTeX's attempts to do good line breaking.  In general it is better to fix the bad break.  In this case, you should allow breaks at the commas in your mathematics expression:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}    

\begin{document}

\textbf{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
do tempor incididunt ut et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam quodque $P,\allowbreak Q ,\allowbreak R ,\allowbreak S
,\allowbreak T,\allowbreak \ldots,\allowbreak X,\allowbreak
Y,\allowbreak Z$, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample with breaking commas]

To do this automatically see [Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/15925) and [Break an inline math formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67440/15925).