# How do I split an inline-math parenthesized list?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, inline

I have some paragraph of text, within which I want to say something like `$( foo, bar, baz, and, so, on)$`. This overfills the line and doesn't break where (I believe) it should.

Questions:

- Why doesn't my formula break even though I don't have an `\left(`-`\right)` pair, nor a group?
- What can I do to make it break reasonably without manually specifying where exactly it should break?

Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
$( number 1, number 2, number 3, number 4, 
number 5, number 6, number 7, number 8, 
number 9, number 10, number 11, number 12, 
number 13, number 14, number 15, number 16, 
number 17)$. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

which results in:
[image]

Comment: add `\allowbreak` after each comma to tell LaTeX this comma is a suitable break point

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode

Comment: Also possibly related [Break an inline math formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67440/break-an-inline-math-formula)