# hyphenation of text within math

Tags: math-mode, hyphenation

I would like text like

```
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair
```

(with `\abcdefghij` defined as `\textit{abc\-defg\-hij}`) to be hyphenated as

```
(abc·defg·hij,·abc·defg·hij)-·pair
```

("·" indicates all possible linebreak points; there would of course need to be hyphens if the adjacent characters on both sides are letters). Let's assume that I need a macro like `\abcdefghij` in many places in the document. How can I achieve the intended hyphenation?

Comment: Don't. If it's hyphenatable, it's not math.

Comment: @egreg Good point. I think the cases where I'd like to do this are defensible because they are a certain type of textual material. But I wouldn't hyphenate numbers, because that just *might* lead to trouble ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyphenation works in math as long as you are not inside a `{}` group which is essentially an `\hbox` in math mode.  `\begingroup` groups are OK though.

As you did not provide a MWE (grumble) I stole one from Hendrik's answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\abcdefghij{%
  \begingroup\mathit{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}}\tmp
  abc\-defg\-hij\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and to end with, one last
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair.
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, this is for sure better than what I propose. (By the way, I noticed that often you don't crop your images. Is this on purpose?)

Comment: Thanks! If I replace `\mathit` by `\textnormal` or `\texttt{\textit{[...]}}` or `\textrm{\sbfont\selectfont[...]}`, I can't get it to work. I looked for other TeX primitives like `\fam` but couldn't find any. Any thoughts?

Comment: the `\text...` commands are `\hbox` so don't allow line breaking, nothing special about `\mathit` there though `\mathrm` or `\mathsf` etc will all work.

Comment: @HendrikVogt well I crop by eye normally in an editor, often I pick up the page margins just to show layout, here I seem to have been a bit generous with white space for no particular reason:-)

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve the intended hyphenation is to put the "syllables" into separate `\textit` commands, separated by discretionary breaks `\-`. (This interferes with the kerning in `abcdefghij`, but works reasonably well.) To allow a line break after the comma, you can use the code from [this answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19100).

[image: output]

Note that I put an italic correction `\/`after the `j` so that it's not that close to the closing parenthesis anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\abcdefghij{\textit{abc}\-\textit{defg}\-\textit{hij\/}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\mathcomma\mathcode`\,
  \mathcode`\,="8000 
}
{\catcode`,=\active
  \gdef,{\mathcomma\discretionary{}{}{}}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and a 
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair and to end with, one last
\((\abcdefghij,\abcdefghij)\)-pair.
\end{document}
```