# How to auto linebreak before/after parenthesis in inline math

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I read this answer ["Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode" breaks citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode-breaks-citations)

I want to change ('s catcode automatically to avoid breaking some packages.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\def\old@lparen{(}
\catcode`\(=13
\def({%
  \ifmmode%
    \discretionary{}{}{}\old@lparen%
  \else% for \mbox, \text, etc...
    \old@lparen%
  \fi}
\catcode`\(=12
\makeatother
\preto{\(}{\catcode`\(=13}{}{}
\appto{\)}{\catcode`\(=12}{}{}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\mid}{\mathopen{}\,|\,\mathclose{}}

\hrulefill

\((A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B)\)

$(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B),(A \mid B)$

\end{document}
```

\( and \) are easily patched with etoolbox but $ and $ are stubbron for me...

### Update

I want a break after `,` (highest priority).
And I want a break before `(` or after `)`

### Update2

I thought "a break before `(` or after `)`" is equivalent to "nolinebreak before/after \mid and operands (in this case)".
But this idea is not correct?

["Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode" breaks citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode-breaks-citations) this page's trick makes linebreak in inner parenthesis (of course, this is normal behavior).

egreg's suggestion looks great except linebreaking rparen followed comma.

I want mixed soulution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you want a break *before* `(`, but rather a possible break after `)`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`)
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\rparen{\Umathcharnum\the\Umathcodenum`) }
  \mathcode`)=\string"8000
}
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\rparen\penalty0 }

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill

\(
 (A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)
 (A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)
\)

$(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)
 (A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)(A \mid B)$

\end{document}
```

Note that this also allows using `\right)`, while your approach would make `\left(` illegal.

The trick is making `)` math active and not active.

[image]

Comment: The trick looks great. But I'm sorry I failed to show correct example.

Comment: @watiko Breaking after `,` has already been dealt with on the site.

Comment: I checked your code(added comma and \\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
) on other environment(https://cloudlatex.io/ xelatex). http://i.imgur.com/DVcKNMJ.png

Comment: @watiko You should only do the comma bit, not the parenthesis.