# How to achieve line break in simple $formula$-mode

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I want to have inline math text like

```
Figure \ref{figure:example graph} shows an example of a graph $G = (\{v_{1}, \dots, v_{5}\}, \{(v_{1}, v_{2}), (v_{2}, v_{3}), (v_{1}, v_{3}), (v_{2}, v_{5}), (v_{3}, v_{4}), (v_{4}, v_{5})\})$ with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.
```

but then, LaTeX messes with the linebreak and the rendered text looks like in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Is there any way, I can tell LaTeX to break the formula within simple $'s?

Comment: Special case of [line breaking - How can I prevent inline math formulas from overflowing into the margin? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/how-can-i-prevent-inline-math-formulas-from-overflowing-into-the-margin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to cope with this is to define a new command for a breakable comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bcomma}{,\allowbreak}

\begin{document}
Figure \ref{figure:example graph} shows an example of a graph 
$G = (\{v_{1}, \dots, v_{5}\}, 
 \{(v_{1}, v_{2})\bcomma
   (v_{2}, v_{3})\bcomma
   (v_{1}, v_{3})\bcomma
   (v_{2}, v_{5})\bcomma
   (v_{3}, v_{4}),
   (v_{4}, v_{5})\})$ 
with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer not to use `\bcomma` after the list of vertices and before the last edge, but in an emergency you can change also those.

[image]

---

A more complex solution can be written with LaTeX3 facilities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mathlist}{ O{,} m m }
 {
  \egreg_mathlist:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_mathlist_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_mathlist:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__egreg_mathlist_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__egreg_mathlist_seq { #2 } { #2 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{figure:example graph} shows an example of a graph 
$G = (\{\mathlist{,}{v_{1}, \dots, v_{5}}\}, 
  \{\mathlist[;]{,\allowbreak}
      {(v_{1}, v_{2});
       (v_{2}, v_{3});
       (v_{1}, v_{3});
       (v_{2}, v_{5});
       (v_{3}, v_{4});
       (v_{4}, v_{5})}
  \})$ 
with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.

\end{document}
```

The `\mathlist` command has an optional argument (the item separator, default a comma); the first mandatory argument tells what to put in place of the separator, the second argument is the list.

The first usage of `\mathlist` in the example is of course redundant; the second one isn't: since the comma is used in the ordered pairs, I choose a semicolon as separator and it's substituted after processing by `,\allowbreak` as in the simpler definition above.

---

If the list of edges is stored in a macro, the method above doesn't work. But the definition can be extended to cope with this case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mathlist}{ s O{,} m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \egreg_mathlist:nnV { #2 } { #3 } #4 }
   { \egreg_mathlist:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_mathlist_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_mathlist:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__egreg_mathlist_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__egreg_mathlist_seq { #2 } { #2 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_mathlist:nnn { nnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\edgelist}{(v_{1}, v_{2}); (v_{2}, v_{3}); (v_{1}, v_{3});
   (v_{2}, v_{5}); (v_{3}, v_{4}); (v_{4}, v_{5})}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{figure:example graph} shows an example of a graph 
$G = (\{\mathlist{,}{v_{1}, \dots, v_{5}}\}, 
  \{\mathlist[;]{,\allowbreak}
      {(v_{1}, v_{2});
       (v_{2}, v_{3});
       (v_{1}, v_{3});
       (v_{2}, v_{5});
       (v_{3}, v_{4});
       (v_{4}, v_{5})}
  \})$ 
with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.

The list of edges can also be obtained by 
$\mathlist*[;]{,\allowbreak}{\edgelist}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For completeness, by default LaTeX is willing to break in-line formulae, but only after relations (e.g. `=`) and binary operators (e.g. `+`) not enclosed between `{..}`.  `\allowbreak` inserts extra break points.

Answer (score 4):

The *simplest* way to achieve what you want is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Figure \ref{figure:example graph} shows an example of a graph 
$G = (\{v_{1}, \dots, v_{5}\}$, 
 $\{(v_{1}, v_{2})$, $(v_{2}, v_{3})$, $(v_{1}, v_{3})$, $(v_{2}, v_{5})$,
 $(v_{3}, v_{4})$, $(v_{4}, v_{5})\})$ 
with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is the simplest to write, I agree. However the spaces after commas is not uniform as it is in the other solutions. On the other hand, the list of edges might be generated via a macro; the method in my answer can be easily extended to cope with this case.

Comment: a +1 from egreg only gives me ten points? not 1000? ;-)

Comment: Sorry. Complain with the Powers That Be. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell LaTeX that it is allowable to break at (say) a `,`. One option is to provide a list parser to insert a breakable point at every `,`. That's provided by this version of [`\mathlist`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/PWt75pamgO8/Btouz_IsZq4J):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/PWt75pamgO8/Btouz_IsZq4J
\newcommand{\mathlist}[2][,]{% \mathlist[<separator>]{<csv list>}
  \begingroup
  % count the elements
  \@tempcnta=\z@
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne}
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list first time
  \chardef\@listsize\@tempcnta
  \@tempcnta=\@ne
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<\@listsize
      ##1#1\penalty\z@ \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    \else
      \unpenalty\penalty\@M ##1
    \fi}
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list second time
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother\begin{document}
Figure~1 shows an example of a graph $G = (\{v_{1}, \dotsc, v_{5}\}, 
\{(v_{1}, v_{2}), (v_{2}, v_{3}), (v_{1}, v_{3}), (v_{2}, v_{5}), 
(v_{3}, v_{4}), (v_{4}, v_{5})\})$ with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.

Figure~1 shows an example of a graph $G = (\mathlist{\{v_{1}, \dotsc, v_{5}\}}, 
\{\mathlist{(v_{1}, v_{2}), (v_{2}, v_{3}), (v_{1}, v_{3}), (v_{2}, v_{5}), 
(v_{3}, v_{4}), (v_{4}, v_{5})}\})$ with $|V| = n = 5$ vertices and $|E| = m = 6$ edges.
\end{document}
```

`\mathlist` parsers the comma-separated list twice. First to find the number of items, and second to set them; this time with a zero penalty after `,`. The last item is not allowed to break.

If you're not concerned about the last item being breakable/not, you can use the following (slightly shorter) definition of `\mathlist`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathlist}[2][,]{% \mathlist[<separator>]{<csv list>}
  \begingroup
  \def\@temp{\penalty\z@}% Put penalty in single token
  \toks@={\@gobble}% Gobble first separator
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\toks@=\@xp{\the\toks@#1\@temp##1}}
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
  \the\toks@% Print list
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the list-parser `\docsvlist`, while [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\@xp` (`\expandafter`) and `\dotsc` (for "comma dots").

`\mathlist` can be supplied with an optional first argument which changes the output from the default `,` to whatever you supply.

Comment: Sorry - does not work for me. I get 

! You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.17 ... $G = (\mathlist{\{v_{1}, \dotsc, v_{5}\}}
                                                  , \{\mathlist{(v_{1}, v_{2...

! Undefined control sequence.
\\mathlist [#1]#2->\begingroup \@tempcnta=\z 
                                             @ \renewcommand *\do [1]{\advan...
l.17 ... $G = (\mathlist{\{v_{1}, \dotsc, v_{5}\}}

Comment: @MichaelKnoll: Since the macro `\mathlist` contains `@` symbols, you need to surround it with a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair. Did you do that?

Comment: The code in the `comp.text.tex` message you're citing deals with a different case, where every comma is eligible as break point. This modification seems too complicated and error prone.