# Two hyphenation problems with non-language items

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, languages, hyphenation

The first hyphenation problem occurs with the double-word "algébrico-géometriques", which is in French, and I'm writing in English. Unfortunately, I already tried different variants of `\hyphenation{...}` which never do anything. Is there a way to teach LaTeX how to break this word?

The second problem is with the polynomial ring

```
$k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.
```

It often produces overfull boxes on the right side of the text, and I don't really know how to deal with it except for reformulating text in the area. Is there a way to make those boxes "breakable"?

Comment: english hyphenation won't do anything with words that contain accented letters.  probably the best option is to insert discretionary hyphens, for example `al\-gé\-brico-géo\-met\-riques` (may not be the best/correct choices for french).  this *should* already be breakable at the existing hyphen, so `sloppypar` may be helpful if it occurs far enough into a paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ad-hoc words that require hyphenation not covered by the language-specific hyphenation patterns, you can use discretionary hyphens `\-` wherever a possible hyphenation break may be needed. For example,

```
al\-gé\-brico-géo\-met\-riques
```

defines four additional points of hyphenation (in addition to the hyphenation already supplied as part of the word).

---

Inline math does not break everywhere regular text would break. Operators and relations are common break-points, but not around `,`. For this, LaTeX needs some encouragement. See [How to achieve line break in simple `$formula$`-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78670/5764) and the use of something like `\mathlist`. It inserts `,\allowbreak` at every `,` which allows a line-break after the comma. Your use case would be

```
$k[\mathlist{x_1,\dotsc,x_n}]$
```

Note that I've used `\dotsc` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). See [Difference of the `\dots`*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122491/5764) for a reference to their uses.

Comment: There's no need to use `\dotsc` here; just `\dots` is sufficient, because a comma *does* follow.