# Split line if too long

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I am sure that this has been answered here many times, but I can't find a duplicate.

My question is what to do with lines that are "too long", i.e. that overflow into the margin. I think the problem has to do with the way LaTeX handles splitting and I seem to remember that there is something that one can insert on a line that turns out too long so that it will be split only if needed. It is something like `\allowsplitline`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent That is we have that $F_A(\pi_A) = F_A(\pi_{A},B)$ is blablabla if and only if $F_A(\pi_{A, B})(7) = \lambda_{\pi_A}(\varpi_A) =\lambda_{\pi}(\varpi_A) = 11$. Text Text Text TextTextText TextTextTextTextTextText   TextTextText
\end{document}
```

Comment: In what context are your lines too long? Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: @Werner: It is part of a long document and I don't seem to be able to take out the part that is causing the problem. I will try some more. There basically is some text and some math and somehow it all comes together so that part of the math runs over the line

Comment: Ahhh, note that math content can only break at certain locations. For example, take a look at [How to achieve line break in simple $formula$-mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78670/5764). Issuing `\allowbreak` at breakable locations might help.

Comment: @Werner: That is it. I was thinking it had to be `\allowlinebreak` but it was even more obvious.

Comment: See [line breaking - How can I prevent inline math formulas from overflowing into the margin? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/how-can-i-prevent-inline-math-formulas-from-overflowing-into-the-margin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `\allowbreak` where needed, or even better, reword the sentence - the breakpoints (after relations and binary operators) are there for a reason.

From [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) (p 207):

> **23.9 Line breaking in math formulas**
>
> In-line formulas can be broken after relations and binary operators. The respective penalties are the `\relpenalty` and the `\binoppenalty`. However, TeX will only break
>   after such symbols if they are not enclosed in braces. Other breakpoints can be created
>   with `\allowbreak`, which is an abbreviation for `\penalty0`.
>
> Unlike in horizontal or vertical mode where putting two penalties in a row is equivalent to just placing the smallest one, in math mode a penalty placed at a break point
>   – that is, after a relation or binary operator – will effectively replace the old penalty
>   by the new one.

If you add `\showoutput` to your MWE, you can see TeX printing the insertion of the penalty *after* the operator `=` but nowhere else (the output below is for `that $F_A(\pi_A) = F_A(\pi_{A},B)$ is`):

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 F
....\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x6.51392, shifted 1.49998
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/7 A
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^Y
....\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x6.51392, shifted 1.49998
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/7 A
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 =
....\penalty 500
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 F
....\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x6.51392, shifted 1.49998
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/7 A
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^Y
....\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x6.51392, shifted 1.49998
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/7 A
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ;
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 B
....\kern0.50172
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
```