# \relpenalty=1000 problem

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I was trying use `\relpenalty` to fix a formula which was breaking and I tried to use `\relpenalty=1000`: turns out now my layout got crazy and most of my images are now at the end of the chapters, in the wrong place... Is there a way I can fix this? I'm supposed to submit my thesis tomorrow... I tried to close TeXshop (I'm using Mac), to save it with another name, to restart the computer, but nothing!! 
Please help me :(

Comment: Uhm... just remove `\relpenaly=1000`. Math-mode line-breaking is very particular. If you which to introduce a singular out-of-the-norm breaking, you're better off to use `\allowbreak`. In particular, see [Split line if too long](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136014/5764).

Comment: If you are using Texshop 3.x (which requires Lion or later), you can perhaps revert to an earlier version. See http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/aboutTeXShopAndLion2.html

Comment: `\relpenalty` usually has the value 500; I don't think that setting it to 1000 can really break everything, unless you have lots of long inline formulas. However, removing the setting should revert the typesetting to the preceding state.