# Avoid badbox with maths in the line

Tags: warnings, badness

I would like to learn to avoid this annoying warnings:

> Overfull \hbox (11.18448pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7

The easiest document possible:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
That is to say, an inertial reference $P$ is like an affine reference $(p_0;v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ such that $\{v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a positively oriented basis of $E$, vector $e_0$ is oriented to the future and...
\end{document}
```

gives me

[image]

If I add `\break` following to "reference", it still gives me the warning. So, how can I fix this warnings? (Indeed I have my documents full of them!, I just want to get rid of them)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28819/117534. You can add the option `draft` to the `documentclass`, and you'll see black boxes where there are `overfull` box errors. Makes it easier to ''debug''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\sloppy` which gives more flexibility in stretching white space, but here it needs to stretch even more than `\sloppy` allows so you get warned of an under full box (and it looks pretty poor).

```
\sloppy
That is to say, an inertial reference $P$ is like an affine reference 
$(p_0;v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ such that $\{v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a positively
oriented basis of $E$, vector $e_0$ is oriented to the future and...
```

[image]

with warning

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1888) in paragraph at lines 5--6
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 That is to say, an in-er-tial ref-er-ence $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 P
$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 is like an affine ref-er-ence
```

with such a short paragraph with large unbreakable units TeX will struggle so you may need to help it a bit, either accepting the above stretched version, or adding breaks by hand

eg without `\sloppy` but a forced break

```
That is to say, an inertial reference $P$ is like an affine reference
$(p_0;\break v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ such that $\{v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a
positively oriented basis of $E$, vector $e_0$ is oriented to the future and...
```

[image]

Comment: Why not add some `\allowbreak` 's? That might be less intrusive

Comment: @daleif if you are only doing it at the end, to force a manual line break, arguably it's no point just hinting. It would be different if you were to make a macro for `(.. ; ....)` that put a possible break point after every `;` then you would just want to allow a break without forcing it.

Comment: I still always use allowbreak. A lot if texts get reused do having to remove those manual breaks after a margin change etc is annoying, thus I  tend to always recommend the allowbreak option and let large decide. Then if the user later on changes stuff there is no harm done.