# How to fix overfull in inline math?

Tags: inline

How do I fix this overfull warning that is caused by the inline math equation? When I used `\sloppy` on the paragraph related, underfull warning appeared instead. I've included a MWE below. If it helps, I use lualatex.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
Firstly, the processing time in the Client-side Mobile Application is calculated by
substracting the end time with the start time, such as $ProcessingTime = EndTime - StartTime$
using the help of an API in React Native.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help with the overfull warning but you should probably do `\(\mathit{ProcessingTime} = \mathit{EndTime} - \mathit{StartTime}\)` for better kerning.

Comment: I don't get any warnings with or without \sloppy.  How old is you version?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm using `Version 4.70b` latexmk with `-pdflua` flag.

Comment: Looks like same question as [line breaking - How can I prevent inline math formulas from overflowing into the margin? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/how-can-i-prevent-inline-math-formulas-from-overflowing-into-the-margin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

- Live with over- and underful boxes as long as they are not too bad.
- Rephrase the sentence to allow for better line breaks.
- Replace inline math by displayed math.

Unrelated: as noted by @Willoughby in the comments, it is better to use `\mathit` for words in math mode that signify variables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

Firstly, the processing time in the Client-side Mobile Application is calculated by substracting the start from the end
time, $\mathit{ProcessingTime} = \mathit{EndTime} - \mathit{StartTime}$, using the help of an API in React
Native.

Firstly, the processing time in the Client-side Mobile Application is calculated by substracting the start from the end
time
\[ \mathit{ProcessingTime} = \mathit{EndTime} - \mathit{StartTime}\]
using the help of an API in React Native.

\end{document}
```