# breqn does not automatically break lines

Tags: breqn

I am writing a two column journal in which I am listing the components of a vector. The vector is too long to fit in one column, and I am using the `\left` and `\right` around the brackets that enclose the vector. However the `dmath` environment does not automatically break the vector into two lines. The code is listed below

```
 \begin{dmath}
 \left(\frac{-(n-1)}{2}h_{12}l,\ldots,\frac{-3}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{-1}{2}h_{12}l, \frac{1}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{3}{2}h_{12}l,
  \ldots,\frac{n-1}{2}h_{12}l\right). \label{eq:x2}
 \end{dmath}
```

The output looks like this

[image: Output from code above]

Any one has an idea how to correct this?

**EDIT:** The preamble of my document is listed below

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
\graphicspath{{../figs/}}
\else
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
\graphicspath{{../figs/}}
\fi
% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breqn}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\section{Some Random Section}
\begin{dmath}
 \left(\frac{-(n-1)}{2}h_{12}l,\ldots,\frac{-3}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{-1}{2}h_{12}l, \frac{1}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{3}{2}h_{12}l,
  \ldots,\frac{n-1}{2}h_{12}l\right). \label{eq:x2}
 \end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: All the code from `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` to `\fi` (included) can safely be replaced simply by `\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{../figs/}}`. If the manual says differently, don't trust it. :)

Comment: These are the template codes that are provided by IEEEtran.sty author. This template is written in 2007. So I guess the codes are a bit outdated.

Answer (score 11):

`breqn` won't break after commas and ordinary atoms, so your formula has no feasible break point. You have to help `breqn` telling it that, in this case, breaking at commas is allowed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=.7\textwidth % just to show the result

\newcommand{\breakingcomma}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,
  \lowercase{\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter~\expandafter{~\penalty0 }}}

\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}\breakingcomma
\left(\frac{-(n-1)}{2}h_{12}l,\ldots,\frac{-3}{2}h_{12}l,
  \frac{-1}{2}h_{12}l, \frac{1}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{3}{2}h_{12}l,
  \ldots,\frac{n-1}{2}h_{12}l\right). \label{eq:x2}
 \end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't make the change permanent: this would break the other formulas in unsuitable places.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use `+` rather than `,` so this just makes comma work like plus. **Note** This also makes `,` have the spacing of a binary operator like `+`.

I suspect it isn't quite the official `breqn` interface, but....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}

\textwidth.5\textwidth

\begin{document}



{\catcode`+\active
\def\foo#1#2#3#4#5{%
\def\tmp{#1,#3#4{2C}}}
\expandafter\foo+
\catcode`,\active
\global\let,\tmp
}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{dmath}
 \left(\frac{-(n-1)}{2}h_{12}l,\ldots,\frac{-3}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{-1}{2}h_{12}l, \frac{1}{2}h_{12}l,\frac{3}{2}h_{12}l,
  \ldots,\frac{n-1}{2}h_{12}l\right) \label{eq:x2}
\end{dmath}

\noindent X\dotfill X




\end{document}
```

As pointed out by @egreg in chat, the fancy redefinition isn't needed and a better solution that doesn't globally redefine comma to be a binary operator is just to explictly allow a break after some (or all) of the commas:

```
\begin{dmath}
 \left(\frac{-(n-1)}{2}h_{12}l,\penalty0 \ldots,\penalty0 \frac{-3}{2}h_{12}l,\penalty0 \frac{-1}{2}h_{12}l,\penalty0  \frac{1}{2}h_{12}l,\penalty0 \frac{3}{2}h_{12}l,\penalty0 
  \ldots,\penalty0 \frac{n-1}{2}h_{12}l\right) \label{eq:x2}
\end{dmath}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the part starting with {\catcode`+\active.... are those pure TeX code instead of LaTeX code? Can you briefly explain what they do?

Comment: It's probably best not to ask:-) But it expands the definition of + (after breqn has redefined it to allow breaking) which it turns out is 5 tokens one of which is `+` and one is `{2B}` which is the hex code for plus. The code then defines , to be the same definition but with , replacing + and 2C (the hex code for comma) replacing 2B,