# breqn: dgroup environment not aligning properly

Tags: alignment, breqn

I'm trying to align a set of equations at the equal signs, with one of them breaking. This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,breqn}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        (A \times B) \cup (B \times A)= \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)\},
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        (A \times B) \cap (B \times A)= \{(3,3)\},
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        (A \times B) \smallsetminus (B \times A)= \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}.
    \end{dmath*}
\end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

The first equation should break somewhere in the middle of the set. However, dgroup* breaks it at the equal sign, completely ruining its alignment. I suspect it's because breqn doesn't like breaking lines at commas; I tried following this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60761/221722) to a related question but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`breqn` has some heuristics for breaking at some places. It will *never* break at commas, because it cannot distinguish between the two commas in `(1,3),`: the first comma *must not* be used for a break, while in your case the second one *might* be used.

Since `breqn`, as well as LaTeX, doesn't really know mathematics, breaking such a display has to be done by somebody who knows.

You can set a break point manually, though. Compare the following two displays and decide which style to adopt.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        (A \times B) \cup (B \times A)=
        \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),\penalty0
        (3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)\},
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        (A \times B) \cap (B \times A)= \{(3,3)\},
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        (A \times B) \smallsetminus (B \times A)= \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}.
    \end{dmath*}
\end{dgroup*}


\begin{align*}
(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) &= \{
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),\\
  &(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)\},
  \end{aligned}
\\
(A \times B) \cap (B \times A) &= \{(3,3)\},
\\
(A \times B) \smallsetminus (B \times A) &= \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]