# How to wrap lines correctly inside algorithmic

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx

I am having problems displaying algorithms. The wrapping is really ugly and I can't, for the life of me, find a fix that doesn't involve manually tweaking the hell out of everything, to the point that I might as well scrap the crappy algorithm packages and write everything out in TeX.

Is there any way to properly indent the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
   \caption{My pseudo code.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \While{this line is sooooooooooo long and boring and too much for algorithmic to handle}
      \State look at this state, this state is just too long for algorithmic to display it properly 
      \While{again this line is sooooooooooo long and boring and too much for algorithmic too handle}
         \State look at this state again, this state is just too long for algorithmic to handle, I'm just going to switch to Word
      \EndWhile
   \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

[image: Ugly algorithm]

so that the output is similar to

[image: Pretty algorithm]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86351/1362 seems to provide a general solution, not tied to specific commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) obviously wasn't intended to manage paragraph-style text as part of pseudo code. You're going to have to do some of your own legwork in order for it to replicate your requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algmargin}{\the\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\newlength{\whilewidth}
\settowidth{\whilewidth}{\algorithmicwhile\ }
\algdef{SE}[parWHILE]{parWhile}{EndparWhile}[1]
  {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algmargin}{%
     \hangindent\whilewidth\strut\algorithmicwhile\ #1\ \algorithmicdo\strut}}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}%
\algnewcommand{\parState}[1]{\State%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algmargin}{\strut #1\strut}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My pseudo code.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \While{this line is sooooooooooo long and boring and too much for algorithmic to handle}
      \State look at this state, this state is just too long for algorithmic to display it properly 
      \While{again this line is sooooooooooo long and boring and too much for algorithmic too handle}
        \State look at this state again, this state is just too long for algorithmic to handle, I'm just going to switch to Word
      \EndWhile
    \EndWhile
    \State
    \parWhile{this line is sooooooooooo long and boring and too much for algorithmic to handle}
      \parState{%
        look at this state, this state is just too long for algorithmic to display it properly}
      \parWhile{again this line is sooooooooooo long and boring and too much for algorithmic too handle}
        \parState{%
          look at this state again, this state is just too long for algorithmic to handle, I'm just going to switch to Word}
      \EndparWhile
    \EndparWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

In the above code, `\parWhile` and `\parState` define the paragraph-style pseudo-code macros that you're after.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! These macros do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\hspace*{5mm}` depending upon the space you need (change `5mm` for your needs).  It is easy and no need to write macros. It works fine with me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an compiling MWE showing your solution for a fast proof?