# Using the algorithmicx package If Then Else, when line is too long indentation breaks

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithmicx

Ignore the Spanish in the code. The problem is that I am getting the `then` clause of the nested `if` with the wrong indentation because of the line break.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}  
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\yLuego}{\land _L}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\algrenewtext{EndIf}{\textbf{fi}}

 \item $ filtrarPorMatch(r,c1,c2) =$ 
 \begin{algorithmic}
 \If{\o?(r)}
     \State \o
 \Else
     \If{$c1 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \land c2 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \yLuego dameUno(r)[c1] = dameUno(r)[c2]$}
          \State $Ag(dameUno(r), filtrarPorMatch(sinUno(r), c1, c2))$
     \Else
         \State $filtrarPorMatch(sinUno(r), c1, c2)$
     \EndIf
 \EndIf
 \end{algorithmic}   

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: then clause looking wrong in filtrarpormatch()]

Any tips on how to solve it or do it better? I must add that I'm new to LaTeX and just starting to understand how it works.

Edit: I solved it like this, but I don't think it's the right way:

```
\If{$c1 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \land c2 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \yLuego \newline
    \hspace*{2em}dameUno(r)[c1] = dameUno(r)[c2]$}
```

Comment: Done. I included all the packages in the original document except `\geometry{a4paper} ` that, for some reason , just prints the line "a4paper" on the document. That does not happen in the original

Comment: What exactly don't you like about the output of your example? It looks aligned correctly to me. Unrelated to the problem: Use `\mathit{variable} for typing variable names in math mode, otherwise the innerword spacing is wrong (see e.g the big space in `dameUno`).

Comment: I pasted the wrong code snippet by mistake... It was filtrarPorMatch. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would suggest to use `\newline` after all logical breaks in your long line -- means after all `\land` and `\yLuego`.

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384017) you can find the definition of a new command `\parState` like:

```
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384017/how-to-wrap-lines-correctly-inside-algorithmic-more-indentation-for-children-l
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\newcommand{\algmargin}{\the\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\algnewcommand{\parState}[1]{\State%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algmargin}{\strut\hangindent=\algorithmicindent \hangafter=1 #1\strut}}
% <=====================================================================
```

Adding that code to your preamble you can then use the following code

```
\If{\parState{$c1 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \land %\newline <==========
    c2 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \yLuego %\newline
    dameUno(r)[c1] = dameUno(r)[c2]$}}
```

to write your longer `\If` statement. Please see that I commented here the included `\newline`. Please try first this variant and compile to see the result, then uncomment the `\newline` commands, compile again and check the changed result. Choose that variant you like more ...

Please see this complete TeX code

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\yLuego}{\land _L}
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384017/how-to-wrap-lines-correctly-inside-algorithmic-more-indentation-for-children-l
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\newcommand{\algmargin}{\the\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\algnewcommand{\parState}[1]{\State%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algmargin}{\strut\hangindent=\algorithmicindent \hangafter=1 #1\strut}}
% <=====================================================================


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\algrenewtext{EndIf}{\textbf{fi}}

\item $ filtrarPorValor (r, c, v) =$ 
\begin{algorithmic}
\If{\o?(r)}
    \State \o
\Else
    \If{\parState{$c1 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \land %\newline <==========
        c2 \in campos(dameUno(r)) \yLuego %\newline
        dameUno(r)[c1] = dameUno(r)[c2]$}}
        \State $Ag(dameUno(r), filtrarPorValor(sinUno(r), c, v))$
    \Else
        \State $filtrarPorValor(sinUno(r), c, v)$
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

After deleting the `%` in front of the `\newline`s you get the changed result:

[image: resulting pdf two]

Please see that I used package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margin. Delete it for your real work, it is only here for testing purposes ...