# Text moving outside of justification margins

Tags: line-breaking

Apologies if the title is incorrect, but I'm not entirely sure how to describe the issue I am having. Please see the image below for clarification. The text should be justified, but in random spots of the document, the text moves across the justification line.

This happens about 3 times in my 20 page document. Two of the occurrences are inline LaTeX as in the attached image, but the other occurrence is a text-only sentence in a text-only paragraph.

An excerpt of text (it might not seem too big a deal now, but if you've got a whole page of text properly justified, that part really sticks out):

[image: Justification problem]

Comment: could you make a complete MWE for folks to play with? make a copy of your document, and strip it until you have something that reproduces the problem. If the inline math is quite long, it might be better to display it on its own line

Comment: At first sight, I would type something like `$v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1},$ $v_n$ and […]`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/15925

Comment: Splitting into two sets of LaTeX (Bernard's answer) and `\allowbreak` (Andrew's link) both work, but I prefer Andrew's referenced method. It seems cleaner and is an acceptable solution for me to work with since I have so few cases of this happening. Andrew please respond to my original question and I will mark it as answer. Thank you all.