# How to allow line breaks in siunitx lists and ranges in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I have written my thesis using `\numlist` and `\numrange` (and the `\SI` variants thereof) from the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. In some cases, I have used these macros in math mode, for instance, `$\phi = \numlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}$`, in contrast to the very explicit advice in the `siunitx` manual that I only now see. With the default settings, this causes the list final separator to be printed in math text (i.e. italics). So I thought, no problem, I'll just wrap the separators in the `\text{}` macro from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), problem solved. Unfortunately, this prevents line breaks from taking place inside the list or range, whether the list or range occurs in math mode or not.

So my question is, can I allow line breaks where I need them by changing `siunitx` settings, or do I have to go through my thesis and remove every `\...range` and `\...list` command from math mode, such that I can remove the `\text{}` around the `list-separator`s?

Demo:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{width=0.5in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\SIrange{750}{1000}{\kelvin} % Breaks

\SIlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}{\percent} % Breaks

$\phi = \numlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}$ % Doesn't break and italics

\sisetup{%
    range-phrase = {\text{ to }},
    list-separator = {\text{, }},
    list-final-separator = {\text{, and }},
    list-pair-separator = {\text{ and }},
}%


\SIrange{750}{1000}{\kelvin} % Doesn't break

\SIlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}{\percent} % Doesn't break

$\phi = \numlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}$ % Doesn't break
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly relevant? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message you link is indeed relevant.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{%
  range-phrase = {\ \linebreak[0]\text{to}\ \nolinebreak},
  list-separator = {\text{, }},
  list-final-separator = {,\ \linebreak[0]\text{and }},
  list-pair-separator = {\ \text{and}\ },
  list-separator = {,\ \linebreak[0]}
}%

\parbox{0pt}{

\SIrange{750}{1000}{\kelvin} % Doesn't break

\SIlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}{\percent} % Doesn't break

$\phi = \numlist{0.5;0.6;0.7}$ % Doesn't break

}
\end{document}
```

The spaces so introduced will participate to stretching or shrinking in the line.

[image]