# How to get Line breaking in Math Tuple in a definition

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, breqn

See the MWE below. The tuple falls outside the margin. If I make the sentence a bit shorter or longer then it works fine.  So this is unreliable.

Now I can off course force line break before the tuple, but (1) that is not very neat and (2) i am curious how to get this line breaking working dynamically.

It should preferable break after a comma, and then start at the beginning of the line (not at the start of the tuple).

*What I tried myself (based on a search here) was using package `breqn` but not a lot of luck.*

**Problem screenshot:**

Overfull \hbox (97.23221pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}  
\begin{document}
 \begin{mydef}
    ab long line so that the tupple is at the end of the line $\left \langle w_{asdasd},v_{asdasd},x_{sdasdsad},y_{asdasd}\right \rangle$ bla bla.
    \end{mydef}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/15925

Comment: To allow line breaks after the commas you could use `$\left \langle w_{asdasd}\right.$, $v_{asdasd}$, $x_{sdasdsad}$, $\left.y_{asdasd}\right \rangle$ `