# Switching back to inline math with "\everymath{\displaystyle}"

Tags: line-breaking, inline

I have "

```
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

in my header (even though I know you all don't recommend this). But the following line won't break at the end of the text part of the margin and instead writes off of the right end.

```
Suppose we want to fit a polynomial which passes through the points
$(-1,4), (0,0), (1,1)$ and $(4,58)$.
```

How do I get it to break? I've searched for an "\inline" command, but can't find one.

Comment: Related:https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/117534?

Comment: the title of the question is misleading as your expression is inline (and allows line breaking at relations and binary operators) and is not affected by the `\everymath` setting at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\everymath{\displaystyle}` is a *really* bad idea:-) but the line breaking is not affected by that. You should use

```
$(-1,4)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(4,58)$
```

as the `,` just like the `and` are part of the textual sentence structure (unlike the `,` in `(0,0)` which is part of the math, and doesn't allow line breaks.