# How to align text behind bullet points

Tags: formatting

The issue is when a bullet goes over 1 line. Then the alignment is broken like this.

[image]

I  have found I can fix this issue by adding spaces to separate the lines, but this feels sub-optimal. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item(a) Let $n$ and $m$ be integers such that $n < m$ and $m \neq 0$. Then $(\frac{n}{m})^2 \leq (\frac{n}{m})$.

\item(b) Every abelian group is cyclic.

\item(c) The group of permutations $S_3$ of \{1,2,3\} is abelian.

\item (d) If * is any commutative binary operation on any set S, then $a * (b * c) = (b * c) * a$.

\item (e) If * is any binary operation on any set S then $a * a = a$ for all $a \in S$. 

\item (f) Every finite group of at most four elements is cyclic.

\item (g) The empty set is a group.

\item (h) The group of permutations $S_{10}$ of \{1,2,3, \dots ,10\} has 10 elements. 

\item (i) The product of any two cycles in the group of permutations $S_8$ of \{1,2,3, \dots,8\} is commutative

\item (j) The set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices with determinant $-1$ is a subgroup of the group GL $(3, \mathbb{R})$, where GL $(3, \mathbb{R})$ is the group of all invertible $3\times 3$ matrices with real number entries. 
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should really use `enumerate` for this. Really.

Comment: certainly this should be an enumerate environment not numbering by hand with (a), (b) etc, but no one can really comment on your posted code as it uses commands for which you have shown no definition, neither `\1` not `\begin{outline}` are defined by default, nor `\mathbb` although we ,may guess that one

Comment: your example code just makes `! LaTeX Error: Environment enumerate* undefined.`  it does not make the output shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` is needed to have list indentation. Therefore, you should use `enumerate` (or similar) *both* in your problems and solutions. In this case I manually use `\emph{Solution}`, but you should have a look at some exam packages for this.

Note that it is `If $*$ is any blah blah` instead of `If * is any blah blah`. They *are different*! Also, there are some places where math mode is also needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1960/156344
\def\old@comma{,}
\catcode`\,=13
\def,{%
  \ifmmode%
    \old@comma\discretionary{}{}{}%
  \else%
    \old@comma%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\emph{Solution}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item Let $n$ and $m$ be integers such that $n < m$ and $m \neq 0$. 
Then $(\frac{n}{m})^2 \leq (\frac{n}{m})$.
\item Every abelian group is cyclic.
\item The group of permutations $S_3$ of $\{1,2,3\}$ is abelian.
\item If $*$ is any commutative binary operation on any set S, then 
$a * (b * c) = (b * c) * a$.
\item If $*$ is any binary operation on any set $S$ then $a * a = a$ 
for all $a \in S$. 
\item Every finite group of at most four elements is cyclic.
\item The empty set is a group.
\item The group of permutations $S_{10}$ of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ has
10 elements. 
\item The product of any two cycles in the group of permutations 
$S_8$ of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,8\}$ is commutative.
\item The set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices with determinant $-1$ is a
subgroup of the group $\mathrm{GL}(3, \mathbb{R})$, where 
$\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ is the group of all invertible $3\times 
3$ matrices with real number entries. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I switch the numbers to lowercase letters? I am looking through everything right now btw, this is very helpful

Comment: @EvanKim Use `(i)` or `(a)` instead of `(1)` after `\begin{enumerate}`. You can even use something like `a.`. For more customizations, remove `shortlabels` option and have a look at the `enumitem` manual.

Comment: Also, inline it's better to use `$(n/m)^2$` instead of `$(\frac{n}{m})^2$`.

Comment: @JPi Yes, but that is the OP's intention. However, the text-mode sets really need improvement.

Comment: @JouleV right, my comment wasn't a criticism of your solution.

Comment: @Jpi Of course I welcome all improvement requests! I don't even think that your comment criticizes me of something :)

Comment: @JPi yea you're right, $(n/m)^2$ looks better inline for sure, thanks