# can I autobreak inline math that runs off?

Tags: line-breaking, inline

is there like a way to just have inline math automatically continue to the next line  when separated by a comma or some other punctuation that normally keeps it on one line

I thought thats what \breqn did but it didn't do that for me also caused confusing bugs.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode

Comment: It's really more reliable to segment the math into separate chunks at the commas, taking into account the mathematical sense of the expression, so that breaks occur in "logical" places.  For example, `$a$, $b$, $f(a,b)$, $c$`, where it would be inappropriate to break at the comma in `$f(a,b)$`.

Comment: It is worth noting that `$a, b, f(a,b), c$` results in different spacing than `$a$, $b$, $f(a,b)$, $c$`, so the method used to allow breaks after the comma is context dependent. If it's inside a set than you should not separate the elements into different math chunks, but place an `\allowbreak` after the commas you want to allow breaks after, while if its a list of variables you want to describe in your text, you should go for different chunks.