# Lua Latex: How to break a long line of elements of a set in inline mode?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, line-breaking, inline

I have a long listing of 2-uple elements like `$A = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), \}$` using inline math mode. LuaLaTeX isn't breaking in multiple lines. How can I force it to break in a comma not inside the tuple, otherwise the set elements goes off page?

The solution proposed at [Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode) didn't work. Seems to break polyglossia.

Comment: If the list is automatically generated, the easiest thing to do would be to make it so that the commas where you want to allow a break are followed by `\penalty 0` or someting like that.

Comment: @Lin just to clarify that is not a LuaLaTeX thing. TeX will not break at commas by default in math mode (as it would be bad to break at the comma inside `(1,2)`. Instead you need to help TeX by telling it which commas are  good to break at. This is done via adding `\allowbreak` after the relevant commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility using a command called `\mySpecialCommas` to make commas active in math mode only when said command is used. When `\mySpecialCommas` is used inside a math formula, a line break after a comma is allowed if, and only if the comma is followed by a space token (which can be obtained from the end-of-line, as usual). So, make sure commas inside your tuples are not followed by a space. Beware of the final comma in your example, unless you are fine with the closing brace appearing at the beginning of a line. This should work with any engine.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\my@specialComma}{%
  \futurelet\next\my@specialComma@next
}

\newcommand*{\my@specialComma@next}{%
  \mathchar "613B             % the normal mathematical comma
  \ifx\next\@sptoken
    \penalty 0                % higher values make a line break less desirable
    \mskip 0mu plus 2mu\relax % add stretchability for better line breaks
  \fi
}

{\catcode`\,=\active
 \gdef,{\my@specialComma}%
}

\newcommand*{\mySpecialCommas}{\mathcode`\,="8000 } %space intended
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-3]
This is a long equation: $\mySpecialCommas
A = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1),
(2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5),
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3) \}$.

\medskip
This is a long equation: $\mySpecialCommas
A = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1),
(2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5),
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),\}$.

\medskip
Normal text can have commas, no problem.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention that you use LuaLaTeX, here's a solution that works by setting up (a) a Lua function that inserts `\allowbreak` instructions if a comma follows a `)` character and (b) a LaTeX front-end macro called `\AllowBreaks`.

[image]

The vertical lines in the preceding screenshot denote the edges of the textblock.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' and '\luastring' macros
\luaexec{
function AllowBreaks ( s )
  tex.sprint ( ( s:gsub ( "\%)\%s-," , "),\\hspace{1sp}\\allowbreak" ) )  )
end
}
\newcommand\AllowBreaks[1]{\luaexec{AllowBreaks(\luastring{#1})}}

\newcommand\LongString{test test test $A = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3) \}$ test test test test}

\begin{document}
\LongString

\bigskip
\AllowBreaks{\LongString}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The third upvote of this answer raised my rep count on this site past 333,333. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This answer does *not* require `lualatex`, but instead relies on the  `tokcycle` package to go through the token stream of the environment content and add `\allowbreak` after commas that fall outside of a paren group.  Also, to mimic something of `\sloppy` input, it throws in some extra glue with spaces to allow stretching/compression (you can adjust the amounts).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\ifx(#1\def\commaaction{}\else
  \ifx)#1\def\commaaction{\allowbreak}\fi\fi
  \addcytoks{#1}\ifx,#1\addcytoks[1]{\commaaction}\fi}
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{\hspace{0pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}#1}}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
$A = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), \}$
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]