# Ordered tuples of ordered tuples

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

The following source includes a definition of `\opair` for typesetting ordered pairs, or tuples, that use angle-brackets as the initial and terminal delimiters; that definition appears in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592421/13492. (I shrank the `3mu` spacings in the original.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\opair}{m}
 {
  \langle\mspace{1mu}
  \kaiserkatze_opair:n { #1 }
  \mspace{1mu}\rangle
 }

\seq_new:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq
\tl_new:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_first_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kaiserkatze_opair:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq { #1 }
  % set off the first item and insert it
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq \l__kaiserkatze_opair_first_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_first_tl
  % now insert commas and allowed breaks
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq
   {
    % comma and thin space
    ,\mspace{1mu plus 1mu minus 1mu}
    % but \allowbreak only after the second item and before the penultimate
    \int_compare:nT { 1 < ##1 < \seq_count:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq }
     { \allowbreak }
    % the item
    ##2
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\opair{1,2}$,  $(1,2)$
\begin{gather*}
\opair{\opair{1,2}, \opair{3,4}}
\\
\bigl((1,2), (3,4)\bigr)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Compare the output with ordinary use of parentheses and big parentheses for the same thing:

[image: ordered pair of ordered pairs]

There are two limitations there:

1. In the case of an ordered pairs of ordered pairs, the parsing is contrary to the intended meaning.
2. As it stands, the definition of `\opair` does not allow for having larger angle brackets, as contrasted with using `\bigl(` ... `\bigr)` in the case of parentheses.

**How can these limitations be overcome?**

Note that for the second issue, it would not suffice to use `\left\langle`...`\right\rangle`. I want to be able to control the size of the angle brackets more finely, so as to use also `\big\langle`...`\big\rangle` and even `\bigg\langle`...`\bigg\rangle`.  For this, it would be OK to have separate macros, named, say, `\bigopair` and `\biggopair` along with `\leftrighopair`.

Related: [big angle brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108767/big-angle-brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `\opair{\opair{1,2}, \opair{3,4}}` is not due to parsing(*) but to recursion and assignments: when the second `\opair` is processed, it sets `\l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq` to a sequence containing the items `1` and `2`, which disturbs what the outer `\opair` was doing: that one now sees an “incorrect” value of `\l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq`. Since the assignments done in `\kaiserkatze_opair:n` are all local, this can be fixed by wrapping the replacement text of `\kaiserkatze_opair:n` in `\group_begin:` ... `\group_end:`.

For the problem of delimiter sizes, you can make `\opair` accept an optional argument that gives the desired size. Here is one way using `mathtools`' `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX { \opair } [1] { \langle } { \rangle }
  {
    \mspace { 1mu }
    \kaiserkatze_opair:n {#1}
    \mspace { 1mu }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq
\tl_new:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_first_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kaiserkatze_opair:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq {#1}
  % set off the first item and insert it
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq \l__kaiserkatze_opair_first_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_first_tl
  % now insert commas and allowed breaks
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq
   {
    % comma and thin space
    ,\mspace { 1mu plus 1mu minus 1mu }
    % but \allowbreak only after the second item and before the penultimate
    \int_compare:nT { 1 < ##1 < \seq_count:N \l__kaiserkatze_opair_items_seq }
     { \allowbreak }
    % the item
    ##2
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\opair{1,2}$,  $(1,2)$\quad
$\opair[\big]{1,2}$,  $\bigl(1,2\bigr)$
\begin{gather*}
\opair{\opair{1,2}, \opair{3,4}} \\
\opair[\big]{\opair{1,2}, \opair{3,4}} \\
\opair[\Big]{\opair[\big]{1,2}, \opair[\big]{3,4}} \\
% The starred form causes \left and \right to be used:
\opair*{\opair{\frac{1}{2},2}, \opair{3,4}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(*) Like macro arguments, items in a `clist` are always brace-balanced.

Comment: How would one include in this a variant `\opair[\lr]`, say, that uses `\left\langle`...`\right\rangle` (so that the outer delimiters stretch just enough for the included content, just like `\left(`...\right)` ?

Comment: You simply need to use `\opair*` (this is documented in the `mathtools` manual). I've added an example of this to my answer.

Comment: The height of the angle brackets with option `\big` seems much too large as compared with `\bigl(`...`\bigr)` whereas normal size parentheses `(` .... `)` seem to have the same height as `\langle`...`\rangle`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't design the math fonts.

Comment: (1) I forgot about the `*` version but should not have! (2) math font design noted!

Comment: Actually, I tried to reproduce this but using the default font, I see the same height with `$\opair[\big]{1,2}$` and `$\bigl(1,2\bigr)$` (see the edited answer). Are you sure you tried this correctly? Maybe you are using a different font?

Comment: The size looked OK with the `newtx` fonts I'm actually using.