# How do I put the formula on one line?

Tags: equations, align

I wrote such a sentence in the latex template.

```
We evaluate $T_r=T_s = \{800,1000,1600,2200,5500,11000\}$.
```

The result shown is this.
[image]

But what is shown in the other template is:
[image]

I want the second way, what should I do? Thanks!
The template I used is: https://hpca-conf.org/2021/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/hpca2021-latex-template.zip

Answer (score 1):

I just found a better solution. That is, split one formula into two.The following formula is feasible.

```
We evaluate $T_r=T_s = \{800,1000,1600,2200,5500,$ $11000\}$.
```

[image]

Comment: Or: `We evaluate $T_r=T_s = \{800,1000,1600,2200,5500,\alllowbreak 11000\}$.`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to solve this problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594470/how-to-make-the-pseudo-code-more-compact

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/158639 --- that way you won't have to manually add `\allowbreak`s after every comma.