# How to make the pseudo code more compact?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, pseudocode

I wrote the following piece of pseudo code. It shows the result as shown in the figure below. I think there is too much white space above the horizontal line in the picture. I want to make them more compact.
Just like the bottom picture, what should I do? Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}   
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{algorithm} [t]
    \caption{Operations }  
    line 0-N : cache lines 
    
    m : 1-bit information
    
    $M[k]$ : k bits message

    \hrulefill  \newline
    \textbf{Encoding:} 
    
    \hrulefill  \newline
    // Encoding Phase \newline
    \eIf{m==1}{
        print a     
    }{  
        print b
    }
    
    sleep; // Allow the receiver code to decode
    

\end{algorithm}  

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with `\myrule` defined as follows: `\newcommand{\myrule}{\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}\hrulefill\vspace{-0.1\baselineskip}}`. Adjust the values according to your needs

Comment: thank you very much. This is working.

Comment: @Ivan I guess you can post that as an answer (maybe with a bit of extra explanation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command `\myrule` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\myrule}{\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}\hrulefill\vspace{-0.2\baselineskip}}
```

Note that the values are determined empirically. So if you change the font, you should probably adjust them.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\myrule}{\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}\hrulefill\vspace{-0.2\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} [t]
  \caption{Operations }  
    line 0-N : cache lines 
    
    m : 1-bit information
    
    $M[k]$ : k bits message

    \myrule

    \textbf{Encoding:} 
   
    \myrule

    // Encoding Phase \newline
    \eIf{m==1}{
        print a     
    }{  
        print b
    }
    
    sleep; // Allow the receiver code to decode
    
\end{algorithm}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the appropriate [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) syntax, ending lines with `\;` and using `\DontPrintSemicolon` if you don't want them printed. Also, there's no need to load [`algorithmic`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) as `algorithm2e` provides all that's needed to produce what you want.

Here's an option using a `tabular` for the "headings":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\newcommand{\algorithmheading}[1]{%
  \rlap{\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algomargin} @{} }
    \hline
    \bfseries\strut #1:\strut \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
    \caption{Operations}
    line $0$-$N$ : cache lines\;
    $m$ : 1-bit information\;
    $M[k]$ : $k$ bits message\;
    \algorithmheading{Encoding}
    // Encoding Phase\;
    \eIf{$m = 1$}{
      print a
    }{
      print b
    }
    sleep // Allow the receiver code to decode\;
\end{algorithm}  

\end{document}
```