# How to split a long set

Tags: line-breaking, alignment, split, alignat, gather

I have this MWE where there are two long set

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
Supponiamo che l'insieme sia $A=\{a,b,c\}$. L'insieme delle parti di $A$ è l'insieme che ha come elementi tutti i possibili sottoinsiemi dell'insieme $A$. Per tutti i possibili sottoinsiemi di $A$ intendiamo proprio tutti i suoi sottoinsiemi, compresi quelli impropri, cioè l'insieme vuoto e l'insieme $A$ stesso.

Abbiamo \[\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \} = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\}= \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\}\]

Devo trovare $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. Se indico gli elementi di $\mathcal{P}(A)$ con $S_1=\emptyset, S_2=\{a\}, \ldots S_8=A$, posso costruire 

$\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))= \{S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5, S_6, S_7, S_8, \{S_1, S_2\},\{S_1, S_3\},\{S_1, S_4\},\ldots\{S_1, S_8\},\{S_2, S_3\}\ldots,\{S_2, S_8\},\ldots\}$
$\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))= \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A, \{\emptyset, \{a\}\},\{\{a\}, \{b\}\},\{\{b\}, \{c\}\},\ldots\{\emptyset, A\}, \{\{a\}, \{b\}\}\ldots,\{\{a\}, A\},\ldots\}$

e così via. È corretto? Se $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^n$ elementi, allora $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))=2^{|\mathcal P(A)|}=2^{2^n}$?

Se la definizione di $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \}$ qual è la definizione di $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ per poter capire come si costruiscono?

\end{document}
```

What is the best method to be able to see them on aligned two o more lines? Break them using, for example a split, or a multiline or to write it consequentially as if it were of the text?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't listen to me, but if it was logic, I wouldn't list it inline. In the first case, wouldn't it make sense to align on the `=`? (I guess that's 'break it up', but I don't really understand what you mean by the second option, so maybe I'm just in the dark.)

Comment: @cfr +1 on the comment. I hope it has made my question clearer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, you mean keep it inline but write it sequentially! Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my opinion is your text better readable, if long sets are written in display math form:

[image]

For this I use `aligned*` and `multlined` of `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
Supponiamo che l'insieme sia $A=\{a,b,c\}$. L'insieme delle parti di $A$ è l'insieme che ha come elementi tutti i possibili sottoinsiemi dell'insieme $A$. Per tutti i possibili sottoinsiemi di $A$ intendiamo proprio tutti i suoi sottoinsiemi, compresi quelli impropri, cioè l'insieme vuoto e l'insieme $A$ stesso.

Abbiamo
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}(A)
    & = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \}  \\
    & = \bigl\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\bigr\} \\
    & = \bigl\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\bigr\}
\end{align*}

Devo trovare $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. Se indico gli elementi di
$\mathcal{P}(A)$ con $S_1=\emptyset, S_2=\{a\}, \dotsc, S_8=A$, posso costruire
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \bigl\{S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4,S_5,S_6,S_7,S_8,  \\
        \{S_1,S_2\},\{S_1,S_3\},\dotsc,\{S_1,S_8\},\{S_2,S_3\},\dotsc,\{S_2,S_8\},\dots\bigr\} \\
        \end{multlined} \\[-\baselineskip]
%\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.6\linewidth]
        \bigl\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}, \{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}, \\
        \{\emptyset,\{a\}\},\{\{a\},\{b\}\},\{\{b\},\{c\}\},\dotsc,A,   \\ \{\emptyset,A\},\{\{a\},\{b\}\},\dotsc,\{\{a\},A\},\dots\bigr\}
        \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
e così via. È corretto? Se $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^n$ elementi, allora $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))=2^{|\mathcal P(A)|}=2^{2^n}$?

Se la definizione di $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \}$ qual è la definizione di $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ per poter capire come si costruiscono?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that there's a general rule that answers your question.

- There will be cases for which it's clearly preferable to put the math material containing commas out of the running text and into a display -- and use of the `amsmath`/`mathtools` multline-display environments, if need be.
- Similarly, there will be cases for which there's no compelling reason to apply the previous choice -- and hence for which a solution may have to be found that allows line breaks at commas while in (inline) math mode.
- And, naturally, there will be cases where one could proceed either way.

Speaking for myself (who else?!), I'd say that for the material at hand, case 1 applies in paragraph (the one that starts with "Abbiamo"/"We have"), while keeping inline math mode would appear to be the better choice in paragraph 3. (See [Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1959/5001) for a method that automates allowing line breaks after commas in inline math mode.) Of course, others may disagree with my view.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype} % <-- optional

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1960/5001:
\makeatletter
\def\old@comma{,}
\catcode`\,=13
\def,{%
  \ifmmode%
    \old@comma\discretionary{}{}{}%
  \else%
    \old@comma%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Supponiamo che l'insieme sia $A=\{a,b,c\}$. L'insieme delle parti di~$A$ è l'insieme che ha come elementi tutti i possibili sottoinsiemi dell'insieme~$A$. Per tutti i possibili sottoinsiemi di~$A$ intendiamo proprio tutti i suoi sottoinsiemi, compresi quelli impropri, cioè l'insieme vuoto e l'insieme $A$ stesso.

Abbiamo 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{P}(A) 
  &= \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \} \\
  &= \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\} \\
  &= \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\} \,.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Devo trovare $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. Se indico gli elementi di $\mathcal{P}(A)$ con $S_1=\emptyset, S_2=\{a\}, \dots, S_8=A$, posso costruire $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))= \{S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4,S_5,S_6,S_7,S_8,\{S_1,S_2\},\{S_1,S_3\},\{S_1,S_4\},\dots,\{S_1,S_8\},\{S_2,S_3\},\dots,\{S_2,S_8\},\dots\}$. $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))= \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},A,\{\emptyset,\{a\}\},\{\{a\},\{b\}\},\{\{b\},\{c\}\},\dots,\{\emptyset,A\},\{\{a\},\{b\}\},\dots,\{\{a\},A\},\dots\}$ e così via. È corretto? Se $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^n$ elementi, allora $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))=2^{|\mathcal P(A)|}=2^{2^n}$?

Se la definizione di $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \}$ qual è la definizione di $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ per poter capire come si costruiscono?

\end{document}
```